# How to make popup 'add' window in Django 3?

Tags: django

In django admin, when there is a ForeignKey or ManyToManyField, there is **[+]** button to add it like this :

[image]

How can I make that **[+]** button with popup window using **forms** in **templates** ?

**UPDATE 01:**

```
I WANT TO CREATE POPUP WINDOW LIKE THIS IN MY TEMPLATE, NOT IN MY ADMIN PANEL.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [admin reverse urls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#reversing-admin-urls).

So in code:

```
<button class="button" onClick="window.open('{% url 'admin:model_add' %}');">
     <span class="icon-plus">+</span>
</button>
```

This is not tested! It's just a quick try out of my brain.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I want to add it in my template not in my admin panel.

Comment: Updated my answer.